# How do I resize temporary image files for increased performance?

Tags: javascript, php, axios

I am building an Instagram app where you can upload images and add filters to them. When uploading an image, you get a preview of that selected image with the filters. On the desktop, the filter display works smoothly, but on an iPhone 6S, scrolling through the filters is laggy and slow. The filters are just css classes from CSSGram.

An image to visualize: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuzQwOkGzbwfmZZbYMI6V-Kxk4Myig

I know how to resize the file before saving. When inspecting the filter images, the size isn't that large so I don't understand why it's so slow on an iPhone.

```
// the javascript file
var uploader = document.getElementById('image');

image.addEventListener("change", function(event){
    // select all hidden elements and show them as soon as an image is selected
    var elements = document.querySelector(".filters");
    var imageWrapper = document.querySelector(".imageWrapper");
    elements.style.display="block";
    imageWrapper.style.display="block";
    var image = document.getElementById('output');

    var F_nofilter = document.querySelector(".F_nofilter");
    var F_1977 = document.querySelector(".F_1977");
    var F_aden = document.querySelector(".F_aden");

    var img = event.target.files[0];



    image.src = URL.createObjectURL(img);
    F_nofilter.src=URL.createObjectURL(img);
    F_1977.src=URL.createObjectURL(img);

})
```

```
// some of the html code as an example
<div class="formField">
    <label for="image">Upload a picture</label>
    <div class="uploadFileWrapper">
        <input type="file" id="image" name="image"">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="imageWrapper">
    <figure>
        <img id="output" class="uploadedImage" visibility="hidden"/>
    </figure>
</div>

<div class="filters">
    <label for="filters">Select a filter</label>
    <div class="filterContainer">
        <div class="caption">
            <p>normal</p>
            <div class="filterButtons">
                <div class="nofilter">
                    <img class="filterOptions F_nofilter" visibility="hidden"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="caption">
            <p>_1977</p>
            <div class="filterButtons">
                <div class="_1977">
                    <img class="filterOptions F_1977" visibility="hidden"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I want better performance on mobile devices by resizing the filter images.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the image appears small on the screen, the representation of it in the memory is still the same. I'm assuming that performing calculations for each filter for a single image is what is bogging it down.

If you are using an external library to which you send image to for adding filters, then you could use canvas to truly resize the image and and get an image object out of canvas to feed to your external filter adding function.

```js
function generateSmallPreviewImage(image, saclingFactor) {
  // Create an empty canvas and get its context
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  // This sets the size of the canvas based on the image size and a scaling factor
  // For example: scalingFactor = 0.5 will half the image size on canvas
  canvas.width = image.width * saclingFactor;
  canvas.height = image.height * saclingFactor;

  // This sets the fill color as white
  context.fillStyle = '#fff';

  // This fills the bg with white color in case a png is uploaded with transparency
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // Draw image on the canvas. This also scales(resizes) it.
  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // Create an empty image object
  var image = new Image();

  // Set the image source as a base64 encoded image from canvas
  image.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');

  // Return the image
  return image;
}
```

Now call this function whenever an image is selected from the `<input type="file"/>` and call this function to get a resized image.

This is one way to call the function:
`element_to_append_image_to.appendChild(generateSmallPreviewImage(image_element, 0.5));`

Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The filters are just css classes from cssgram, so no external library is used. The image is not saved yet. Only after pressing the "post" button at the bottom of the page (not shown on the screenshot) do I actually save it.

Comment: Alright. So you can use the function to generate smaller image and append them to the preview div. The css filters would then do the trick.